# Please how can I undo ''php artisan livewire:make product-ratings''

Tags: laravel

After running the command I realized that I don't want to use it again so I deleted the two components it created which are

CLASS: app/Http/Livewire/ProductRatings.php

VIEW:  resources/views/livewire/product-ratings.blade.php

Now when I try to access my product in the frontend I get this error

include(C:\xampp\htdocs\keyi\vendor\composer/../../app/Http/Livewire/ProductRatings.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: I still have the error after running it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 possibilities

You have actually deleted it but it still thinks its there so do php artisan view:clear

or
It seems like you are trying to access a Livewire component that has been deleted, but your application is still trying to include it. This is causing the error message "include(C:\xampp\htdocs\keyi\vendor\composer/../../app/Http/Livewire/ProductRatings.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory".

To resolve this issue, you will need to remove any references to the deleted Livewire component from your code. This could include removing references to it in your routes, controllers, views, or other parts of your application.

Once you have removed all references to the deleted component, you should be able to access your product in the frontend without encountering the error message. If you continue to have trouble, you may want to check your logs or run your application in debug mode to get more information about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [`livewire:delete`](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/artisan-commands#delete-command)

```
php artisan livewire:delete product-ratings
```

and run

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
composer dump-autoload # if needed
```

---

saw this command in the web `livewire:remove`.(Not sure if exist)

```
php artisan livewire:remove product-ratings
```